# file size differences - requests module vs chrome

Tags: python, http, web, python-requests

I am really really puzzled with an issue I'm running into. I have a script that is downloading image files off of imgur. The script leverages the requests module.  In essence, a request is made to open the link as a byte stream, and then the file is downloaded into chunks and placed in an in-memory buffer. Here is a very simple version of what I do:

```
page_binary_string = io.BytesIO
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE, decode_unicode):
    page_binary_string.write(chunk)
```

In this case, decode_unicode is going to be set to false.  I then write the resulting stream to a file using

```
image_file = open(path, 'wb')  # Open file for updating
image_file.write(page_binary_string.read(page_binary_string.size))
```

When I look at the resultant file in the file system, it is 1/20 of the size of the file the browser downloaded!!!

Here is the link I am experimenting with at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TldnI.jpg

If you download this file with the browser, you can see that it is 244KB. When I look at the file on disk, it is only 10KB. This size difference is obvious when opening the image.  The quality has drastically deteriorated.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?  Something with the HTTP header (encodings??) was my first guess, but I'm not really sold on this.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no specific reason why you use io.ByteStream you can use the requests module's own raw content functionality. Take a look here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content You can either do it that way, or you could open a file in binary mode (open('somefile.jpg', 'wb')) and dump the contents in there for quick and dirty stuff.

Comment: If I were to just dump the entire request into another object (a pil image or a file), I would commit to downloading the entire contents of the response. I'm iterating over the response in chunks so that I can track it's total size (the http response header might be wrong). If the response's size exceeds a set value, I abort the download. This api will be accessible to the general public, so I needed to account for malicious users.

Answer (score 0):

I want paying attention. I was changing the image format downstream. The above code works